# Missing Screenshot Status in itunes connect

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

[image: missing screenshot image]

I am developing an application in `rhomobile` and made a build for iOs as `.ipa` file and after uploading my binary file through the application loader into iTunes connect I get an error status as Missing Screenshots which I have attached . I have added 2 screen shots in 3.5 and 4 inch display where 3.5 image sizes are `320*480` and 4 inch screenshots of size `640*960` .I have not added any screenshots for iPad as this app is only for iPhone .Do I need to add iPad screenshots. I also have deleted a launch image `namedDefault-568h@2x.png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to note.

1. If your application is `Universal`, you need to upload screenshot for all the devices
2. If your application is `iPhone`, you need to upload screenshot for iPhone4, and iPhone 5 Devices.
3. Same for if its only `iPad`.
4. If your app supports multiple languages you need to select language see below

   [image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: is there any way to change the universal into iphone in itunesconnect

Comment: NO, it can be done from the App settings only in Xcode

Comment: I made a build through rhohub mobile and i am pushing that .ipa file through application loader .i have uploaded 2 screenshots each for 3.5 inch (640*960) and 4 inch (640*1136) .do i need to add 5 screenshots for each or 2 is enough for both 3.5 and 4 inch .Do i need to add ipad and 4 inch screen shot with the resoultion (1136*640).

Comment: No only one screenshot is enough for proceedings, you can later add more screenshots while the app is in `Review`.

Comment: Is it necessary to add a screenshot with (1136*640) under the 4 inch screenshot or can i add one screen shot of size(640*1136) alone

Comment: You can add any one of them.

Comment: still i am getting missing screenshots same error not solved

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35820/discussion-between-iphonic-and-arunmak)

Comment: i just missed my ipad screen shot so got the error .Solved it.Thanks